# A field not declared optional accepted null as the value

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a data class

```
data class Bean {

    var value: String = ""

}
```

I got a Json from server:

```
{
    "value":null
}
```

What I expect is since `value` is not optional, so the null cannot be assigned and `value` will remain as `""`. But using the debugger I found that `value` is null, and therefore some method I called on it throws the below exception:

```
fun matches(stringToMatch: String): Boolean {
    return this.value.toLowerCase() == stringToMatch.toLowerCase()
}
```

`kotlin.TypeCastException: null cannot be cast to non-null type java.lang.String`

How can I make `value` remains `""`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're using a JSON deserialization library (GSON?) that creates your objects by completely sidestepping the initialization you built into them. Most probably it uses a low-level, non-JDK call `sun.misc.Unsafe.allocateObject()` to allocate a raw data block for your object and then proceeds to populate it from parsed JSON.

The only way to truly fix this is using such a JSON library that understands Kotlin and can replicate its object initialization rules.

BTW your specific JSON example, which explicitly assigns `null` to a non-null property, should not use the default value, but throw a validation exception.

Comment: Yes I am using Gson. So... actually I should have declared all fields optional?

Comment: That's the only way to match what GSON is about to do with them. And provide no other default but `null`. As a workaround you can build such a "raw" object for deserialization only, and then create your real domain object by passing the raw one in, and then apply all the logic of copying the data.